# Is my proof to calculate the length of a line correct?

Tags: calculus, geometry, derivatives

Recently I misunderstood a test-question for calculating the length of given function $a(x)$ between $x = A$ and $x = B$. Even though this was not the question which I should have answered, it intrigued me, and I was wondering if I could find such a formula. Here is what I found:

Say we got the function $a(x)$. First we create function $f(x) = |a(x)|$, because $l_{a(x), A, B} = l_{f(x), A, B}$, and $l_{f(x), A, B}$ is easier to calculate, or so I figured. Then we ask ourselves, what is the length of $f(x)$ between $p$ and $p + dx$. I made a right-angled triangle (see picture)
[image: The triangle I thought of]

with $\alpha = \tan{(f'(x))}$.
$$\alpha = \tan{(\frac{h}{dx})}$$
$$\tan{^{-1}(\alpha)} = \frac{h}{dx}$$
$$f'(x) = \frac{h}{dx}$$
$$h = f'(x) * dx$$
Which is logical, because the primitive function of $f'(x) = f(x) = h$, of course. However, continuing using the triangle I found that using Pythagoras' function, we can, as you probably have seen already, calculate $l_{dx}$:
$$l_{dx} = \sqrt{dx^2 + h^2} = \sqrt{dx^2 + (f'(x) * dx)^2} = \sqrt{dx^2 + f'(x)^2 * dx^2} = \sqrt{dx^2(f'(x)^2 + 1)} = \sqrt{f'(x)^2 + 1} * dx$$
About then, I started thinking of the Riemann-sums (saying that $\int_A^B f(x)dx \approx \sum_{k=A}^B (f(x) * dx)$), and as we are dealing with about a similar problem here, it must be that, or so I thought, 
$$l_{f(x), A, B} = \int_A^B \sqrt{f'(x) + 1} * dx$$
My questions are whether this is correct, and if there is any way to calculate the antiderivative of $g(x) = \sqrt{f'(x) + 1}$.

Comment: There aren't so many function for which analytical integration is possible. You can try the parabola, the circle or the exponential.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, yes, obiously it is correct, and no, the antiderivative of $\sqrt{f'(x) + 1}$ is not easily to be found.

Comment: The square seems missing.